# Nested safe call Null check Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to display an image in an ImageView, so I need to make sure that the image url is not null first. Are these 3 options valid?

**Answer data class**

```
data class Answer(
    val id: Long?,
    val title: String?,
    val answerImage: AnswerImage?
) {
    data class AnswerImage(
        val x0: AnswerImageData?,
        val x1: AnswerImageData?,
        val x2: AnswerImageData?
    ) {
        data class AnswerImageData(
            val id: String?,
            val url: String?
        )
    }
}
```

**Option 1**

```
answer.answerImage?.let { answerImage ->
     answerImage.x0?.let { answerImageData ->
        answerImageData.url?.let {
             //display image
         }
      }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
if (answer.answerImage?.x0?.url != null)
{
   //display image
}
```

**Option 3**

```
answer.answerImage?.x0?.url?.let {
      //display image
}
```

Comment: Do they compile? Do they correctly check for nullness? Yes? then they're valid. that's something that you can test easily by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

- Option 1: Would only be a good choice if you actually need to do more things with `answerImage` and `answerImageData` rather than just cast it safely. In this specific case, we don't have a use for declaring those variables explicitly. To conclude: option 1 in this case is not a very neat solution, but it does work.
- Option 2: should work, because all attributes are immutable. The compiler can then deduce on the next line (inside `if` scope), that the `url` property will still be non-`null`.
- Option 3: this is in my opinion the best one: it's the easiest one to process as a reader of the code, as you would generally finish it with code like this: `.let { safeUrl -> .. }`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with option 3 then.

Answer (score 4):

As specified by @Ken Van Hoeylandt all 3 options are valid, another valid option could be to use elvis operator:

```kotlin
fun attemptDisplayingImage(answer: Answer) {
    val answerImage = answer.answerImage ?: return
    val answerImageData = answerImage.x0 ?: return
    val answerImageDataUrl = answerImageData.url ?: return
    // display image
}
```

There's an interesting article about this topic [here](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/kotlins-elvis-better-than-swift-s-guard-53030d403c3f)

Answer (score 2):

Ken covered the answers (they're all fine and do the same thing, the last one is how the language is designed to be used really, nice and neat!) but I wanted to touch on your actual data model.

First, you say you need to check that an `AnswerImageData`'s `url` isn't null. But the only reason it *could* be null, is because you've explicitly made it nullable, with a `String?` type. Is an `AnswerImageData` with a null `url` *ever* valid? Or does it *always* need to have one? I'm guessing it does, and I'm guessing it always needs an `id` too - so just make them non-null!

```
data class AnswerImageData(
    val id: String,
    val url: String
)
```

Now *all* your `AnswerImageData` objects are guaranteed to have non-null values - they're all valid in that sense, it's baked into your design. So you don't need to null check them anymore!

And the same goes for your other classes - can you have an `AnswerImage` with null values? This might be a trickier one, let's assume there needs to always be **at least one** `AnswerImageData` in an `AnswerImage` - in which case you can make the first non-null, and the others optional:

```
data class AnswerImage(
    val x0: AnswerImageData,
    val x1: AnswerImageData?,
    val x2: AnswerImageData?
)
```

This isn't necessarily the best way to do this - I'd personally prefer a `vararg` parameter, or some kind of collection, so you can have an arbitrary number of `AnswerImageData`s and do operations like `.first(predicate)` to loop over them all easily. But if you want exactly three slots, three parameters is a way to do it!

Same goes for `Answer` - I'm guessing that *requires* an `id`, `title` and `answerImage` - if so, don't let them be null. Enforce that valid structure through your types, it'll make your life a lot easier! And so will avoiding nullable types unless you actually need them!

---

I don't know if that applies to what you're doing, but it probably does, so it's worth mentioning. (This kind of thing is called *Domain-Driven Design if you want to look into it - basically enforcing the rules and structure of your business logic through the way you design your code, your types, your objects etc.)

Comment: I made AnswerImageData's url nullable because that's data that I get from a Rest API which I don't own, and don't have much information about its implementation so I assume it can be null. This is a sample request http://demo2373134.mockable.io/buffs/1

Comment: Well, say you get a null url back - is that still a valid `AnswerImageData` (or whatever) that you want to keep hold of? Or is it invalid, something you're not going to use? You can have a function that takes your API response, validates it, and creates an `AnswerImageData` if (and only if!) it has all the data you need. That way you're only creating valid objects, so the class doesn't need to be able to represent invalid state, if you get me. So now you never need to worry about handling it. I don't know exactly what you're doing and whether you need to keep them anyway, but it might help!

Answer (score 1):

All the answers above were great but I wanted to mention something. You declared your properties as nullable so I'm guessing you are getting them from somewhere else (from your data layer if you're familiar with clean architecture).

my recommendation is to create a domain model for your class and map the data to your domain model(which has non-null properties). this way you handle nulls in the mapper. it's cleaner and follows the separation of concerns and single responsibility principles.

```
interface Mapper<F, S> {
    fun firstToSecond(first: F): S
    fun secondToFirst(second: S): F
}
```

```
data class DataModel(
    val id: Long?,
    val title: String?,
    val answerImage: AnswerImage?
)

data class DomainModel(
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val answerImage: AnswerImage
)
```

```
class DataToDomainMapper: Mapper<DataModel, DomainModel> {
    override fun firstToSecond(first: DataModel): DomainModel {
        return DomainModel(
            id = first.id ?: -1,
            title = first.title ?: "no title",
            answerImage = first.answerImage ?: AnswerImage()
        )
    }

    override fun secondToFirst(second: DomainModel): DataModel {
        return DataModel(
            id = second.id,
            title = second.title,
            answerImage = second.answerImage
        )
    }
}
```

this way you don't have to handle nulls anywhere else in your code. and for data validation, you can check the id not to be negative. I've shortened your models, but you get the idea

Comment: This is great, thank you. Definitely adding domain and data models

Comment: glad I could help